# jQuery - Destroy and reinitialize plugin on click

Tags: jquery, zooming

I'm using the following zoom plugin on my site: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

It works using mouseenter and mouseleave events. I'm trying to make this work with click. Click to zoom and unzoom(?) and also unzoom on mouseleave.

The click to initialize works with the code below but I'm looking to add destroy or stop the function on second click or mouseleave OR even click to a new slide. (It's inside a carousel slider) Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
jQuery('span.zoom img').bind('click',function(){
    jQuery("span.zoom img").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair",
        responsive: true,
        scrollZoom: true
    });
});
```

EDIT: I've scrapped the above situation and created my own zoom. The movement is giving me trouble now. Link: http://bigideaadv.com/pic_site/?p=95

```
    jQuery("div.zoom2 img.rsImg2").mousemove(function(e) {
        var zoom = jQuery(this);
        var position = zoom.position();

        //console.log(position);

        jQuery(".rsImg2").css({"left" : position.left, "top" : position.top});

        // the first parameter (e) is automatically assigned an event object

        //TODO: Uncomment
        var parentOffset = jQuery(this).parent().offset();
        //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

        jQuery(".rsImg2").css({"left" : relX, "top" : relY});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you toggled a class via click? I haven't tested, but it's worth a shot. You will need to loop through each image like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('span.zoom img').each(function() {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    self.click(function() {
        self.toggleClass('doZoom');    
    });
});

jQuery('.doZoom').elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    responsive: true,
    scrollZoom: true
});

});
```

Comment: So following your code snippit, I've got it where it initializes with the click. I had to add the .elevateZoom function inside another function call within the each function which checks if "span.zoom img" has the doZoom class. Now I need to a way to destroy the instance of elevateZoom on click. Is that easy enough to do?

Comment: What happens now when you click again after clicking to zoom?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I ended up making my own zoom. It's a simple swap for the same image that is x2 the size. I've added my code where it moves the image on mousemove. The move is not working as intended. I've included a link too. Any thoughts?